# Local hostnames for Docker containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Beginner Docker question here,

So I have a development environment in which I'm running a modular app, it is working using Docker Compose to run 3 containers: server, client, database.

The `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
#############################
# Server
#############################
server:
  container_name: server
  domainname: server.dev
  hostname: server
  build: ./server
  working_dir: /app
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
  volumes:
    - ./server:/app
  links:
    - database

#############################
# Client
#############################
client:
  container_name: client
  domainname: client.dev
  hostname: client
  image: php:5.6-apache
  ports:
     - "80:80"
  volumes:
   - ./client:/var/www/html

#############################
# Database
#############################
database:
  container_name: database
  domainname: database.dev
  hostname: database
  image: postgres:9.4
  restart: always
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
    - POSTGRES_DB=dbdev
    - PG_TRUST_LOCALNET=true
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"
  volumes:
    - ./database/scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d # init scripts
```

You can see I'm assigning a .dev domainname to each one, this works fine to see one machine from another one (Docker internal network), for example here I'm pinging `server.dev` from `client.dev`'s CLI:

```
    root@client:/var/www/html# ping server.dev
    PING server.dev (127.0.53.53): 56 data bytes
    64 bytes from 127.0.53.53: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.036 ms
```

**This works great internally, but not on my host OS network.**

For convenience, I would like to assigns domains in MY local network, not the Docker containers network so that I can for example type: client.dev on my browsers URL and load the Docker container.

Right now, I can only access if I use the Docker IP, which is dynamic:

```
client: 192.168.99.100:80
server: 192.168.99.100:3000
database: 192.168.99.100:5432
```

Is there an automated/convenient way to do this that doesn't involve me manually adding the IP to my /etc/hosts file ?

BTW I'm on OSX if that has any relevance.

Thanks!

**Edit:** I found this Github issue which seems to be related: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2335

As far as I understood, they seem to say that it is something that is not available outside of the box and they suggest external tools like:

- https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework
- https://github.com/bnfinet/docker-dns
- https://github.com/gliderlabs/resolvable

Is that correct? And if so, which one should I go for in my particular scenario?

Comment: I've never used docker, but IPv4 addresses in the 127.0.0.0/8 range are defined as loopback.  That would not allow any communicatios outside the machine

Comment: This is not much of a docker question, as it is a networking question.  You want to know how your hostOS can have dynamic host aliases (in case docker ip changes) yes?  I think you could combine a `docker ps -a | grep 192` command with concepts from https://books.google.com/books?id=HggtWI1ShvMC&pg=PT142&lpg=PT142&dq=how+to+set+a+host+alias+as+an+environment+variable+/etc/hosts&source=bl&ots=PSOwZZOwVs&sig=TEHiz2Ef_a36AEhXigSAi0hWsI0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdmpz-tdTLAhUIy2MKHZW3CTcQ6AEIWDAJ#v=onepage&q=how%20to%20set%20a%20host%20alias%20as%20an%20environment%20variable%20%2Fetc%2Fhosts&f=false

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Since [it seems that there is no native way to do this with Docker](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2335#issuecomment-152359554), I finally opted for this [alternate solution](http://cavaliercoder.com/blog/update-etc-hosts-for-docker-machine.html) from Ryan Armstrong, which consists in dynamically updating the `/etc/hosts` file.

I chose this since it was convenient for me since this works as a script, and I already had a startup script, so I could just append this function in to it.

> The following example creates a hosts entry named docker.local which
> will resolve to your docker-machine IP:
>
> ```
> update-docker-host(){
>     # clear existing docker.local entry from /etc/hosts
>     sudo sed -i '' '/[[:space:]]docker\.local$/d' /etc/hosts
>
>     # get ip of running machine
>     export DOCKER_IP="$(echo ${DOCKER_HOST} | grep -oE '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}')"
>
>     # update /etc/hosts with docker machine ip
>     [[ -n $DOCKER_IP ]] && sudo /bin/bash -c "echo \"${DOCKER_IP}   docker.local\" >> /etc/hosts"
> }
>
> update-docker-host
> ```

This will automatically add or udpate the `/etc/hosts` line on my host OS when I start the Docker machine through my startup script.

Anyways, as I found out during my research, apart from editing the hosts file, you could also solve this problem by [setting up a custom DNS server](https://engineering.salesforceiq.com/2015/10/08/up-the-rabbit-hole-part-i-a-docker-machine-dns-server.html):

Also found several projects on Github which apparently aim to solve this problem, although I didn't try them:

- https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework
- https://github.com/bnfinet/docker-dns
- https://github.com/gliderlabs/resolvable

Comment: Another rather elegant solution I've found for resolving container names to IP addresses from the docker host is nss-docker https://github.com/dex4er/nss-docker

Comment: Can the script you use in this answer be included within the yaml file? How best to include this script?

Answer (score 23):

Extending on @eduwass's own answer, here's what I did manually (without a script).

1. As mentioned in the question, define the `domainname: myapp.dev` and `hostname: www` in the `docker-compose.yml` file
2. Bring up your Docker containers as normal
3. Run `docker-compose exec client cat /etc/hosts` to get an output of the container's hosts file (where `client` is your service name)
   (Output example: `172.18.0.6    www.myapp.dev`)
4. Open your local (host machine) `/etc/hosts` file and add that line: `172.18.0.6  server.server.dev`

If your Docker service container changes IPs or does anything fancy you will want a more complex solution, but this is working for my simple needs at the moment.

Comment: I were searching in all internet for this. Thank you so much

Comment: Good to know that there's a handy (open-source) tool for editing your hosts file on a mac. See: https://github.com/2ndalpha/gasmask 

Saves me a lot of time searching ;)

Comment: You better not use container's private ip. The ip of each container is assigned to it dynamically at its creation, which means you will have to update `/etc/hosts` with the new ip whenever a container is re-created. Expect manual tedious work if you have multiple containers with domains...

Answer (score 3):

Another solution would be to use a browser with a proxy extension sending the requests through a proxy container that will know where to resolve the domains to. If you consider using [jwilder/nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) for production mode, then your issue can be easily solved with [mitm-nginx-proxy-companion](https://github.com/artemkloko/docker-mitm-nginx-proxy-companion).

Here is an example based on your original stack:

```
version: '3.3'

services:

  server:
    build: ./server
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./server:/app

  client:
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST: client.dev
    image: php:5.6-apache
    volumes:
    - ./client:/var/www/html

  database:
    image: postgres:9.4
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
      - POSTGRES_DB=dbdev
      - PG_TRUST_LOCALNET=true
    volumes:
      - ./database/scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d # init scripts

  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    labels:
      - "mitmproxy.proxyVirtualHosts=true"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

  nginx-proxy-mitm:
    dns:
      - 127.0.0.1
    image: artemkloko/mitm-nginx-proxy-companion
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
```

- Run `docker-compose up`
- Add a proxy extension to your browser, with proxy address being `127.0.0.1:8080`
- Access `http://client.dev`

The request will follow the route:

- Access a local development domain in a browser
- The proxy extension forwards that request to `mitm-nginx-proxy-companion` instead of the “real” internet
- `mitm-nginx-proxy-companion` tries to resolve the domain name through the dns server in the same container

  - If the domain is not a “local” one, it will forward the request to the “real” internet
  - But if the domain is a “local” one, it will forward the request to the `nginx-proxy`
- The `nginx-proxy` in its turn forwards the request to the appropriate container that includes the service we want to access

---

Side notes:

- `links` removed as it's outdated and is replaced by Docker networks
- you don't need to add domain names to `server` and `database` containers. `client` will be able to access them on `server` and `database` domains because they are all in the same network (similar to what `link` was doing previously)
- you don't need to use `ports` on `server` and `database` containers because it only forwards ports to be used through `127.0.0.1`. PHP in `client` container will do only "back-end" requests to other containers, and because those containers are in the same network, you already can access them with `database:5432` and `server:3000`. The same goes for `server <-> database` connections.
- I am the author of `mitm-nginx-proxy-companion`

Comment: I've updated the docker image solution of @artem-titkov and it's available on [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/hypery2k/mitm-nginx-proxy-companion) (for ARM64 and AMD64 ....

Answer (score 1):

My Bash script WITH ALIAS without docker-machine
Based on http://cavaliercoder.com/blog/update-etc-hosts-for-docker-machine.html

```
#!/bin/bash

#alias
declare -A aliasArr
aliasArr[docker_name]="alias1,alias2"

# clear existing *.docker.local entries from /etc/hosts
sudo sed -i '/\.docker\.local$/d' /etc/hosts

# iterate over each machine
docker ps -a --format "{{.Names}}" \
| while read -r MACHINE; do

    MACHINE_IP="$(docker inspect --format='{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' ${MACHINE} 2>/dev/null)"
    
    if [[ ${aliasArr[$MACHINE]} ]]
    then
        DOMAIN_NAME=$(echo ${aliasArr[$MACHINE]} | tr "," "\n")
    else
        DOMAIN_NAME=( ${MACHINE} )
    fi

    for addr in $DOMAIN_NAME
    do
        echo "add ${MACHINE_IP} ${addr}.docker.local"
        [[ -n $MACHINE_IP ]] && sudo /bin/bash -c "echo \"${MACHINE_IP} ${addr}.docker.local\" >> /etc/hosts"
        export no_proxy=$no_proxy,$MACHINE_IP
    done
        
done
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make whole domain for localhost you can use [dnsmasq](https://gist.github.com/marek-saji/6808114). In this case if you chose the domain **.dev** any subdomain will point to your container. But you have to know about [problems](https://iyware.com/dont-use-dev-for-development/) with **.dev** zone

Or you can use bash script for launch your docker-compose which on start will add line to /etc/hosts and after you kill this process this line will removed

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sudo sed -i '1s;^;127.0.0.1    example.dev\n;' /etc/hosts

trap 'sudo sed -i "/example.dev/d" /etc/hosts' 2

docker-compose up
```